# How FB created FBML?

Tags: php, c++, html, fbml, facebook-fbml

I am really interested in how FB created FBML and how to go about creating something similar. Did they write a C++ processor that replaces FBML with HTML or do they use XSLT or what did they do to create a templating language like that? I am wanting to do this mainly for my own knowledge and fun on my spare time to see if i am able to build something similar. Ive tried looking up how they made it but all I get is ways to use FBML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are 3 ways to write a parser for XML that converts to HTML:

1. write a parser in lex and bison
2. use an XML parser library to read the XML into memory, and us a "normal" programming language to convert the XML to HTML.
3. use XSLT
4. use some web framework that supports custom tag libraries that can convert the FBML tags to HTML.

Option #1 is bascially not done since you can always use #2 instead.

Judging from the the fact that some of the tags need to talk to resources outside of the XML file (e.g. `fb:if-can-see`), #2 and #4 seem more likely than #3 -- both would have easier access to SQL databases or NoSQL databases and the like.

(The XSLT libraries in many languages allow one to define custom functions that can access arbitrary data sources in the language they are implemented, so #3 isn't impossible).

Comment: Well I was mainly wondering general stuff about parsing stuff like that so just knowing that it was probably a parser just like parsing PHP was all I needed to know. Cause theres no way I can build a parser like that unless it was able to be done with web based languages. Im not proficient in C or C++ etc. LOL But your answer was better. :)

Answer (score 3):

If it is a Facebook app, then a browser such as FF or IE connects to `app.facebook.com/some_app`, and the Facebook server will connect to `www.foobar.com/blah` (which the app creator register with Facebook) for the FBML code, and Facebook can change it to whatever it wants -- changing the FBML into XHTML.   They can use parsers to parse the FBML code, and convert it into XHTML accordingly.

Comment: So these are just normal parsers like that parse JavaScript and PHP?

Comment: yes, there are many parsers written in different languages, and in the old days using C, people use lex and yacc to do scanning and parsing.  There probably are newer tools than those.

Comment: What would constitute an "abnormal parser" Corey? :D

Comment: I can't believe he accepted this answer. As far as I can see, it basically doesn't answer the question.